# Passing date object from user input to db (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have been trying unsuccessfully so far to save certain data into a database model. Problem as far as I can figure out its the date object, no matter what I do, it wont save. The date is a user input from a form.

```
@app.route('/upload/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method=='POST':
        something = Schedule(
        start_time = request.form.get('start_time'),
        end_time = request.form.get('end_time'),
        duration =  request.form.get('duration'),
        action =  request.form.get('action'),
        location_name = request.form.get('location_name'), 
        vehicle_name = request.form.get('vehicle_name'),
        post_time = request.form.get('post_time'))
        db.session.add(something)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')
```

That is the route.

The following is the model

```
class Schedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = db.Column(db.String(20))
    end_time = db.Column(db.String(20))
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer) 
    action = db.Column(db.String(20))
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    vehicle_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    post_time = db.Column(db.DateTime())
```

I am getting a `200` when I access the route, but only a row is added with no data except the (id) field auto increments. I could also be completely wrong about what the issue is to start with.

Comment: Can you please try to make the id field as auto_increment 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True). I suppose right now nothing is being added since you are not adding the id field while saving the data

Comment: I don't think that is an issue because the database is empty. I also believe sqlalchemy takes care of that

Comment: As far I used postgres we need to make the primary key as auto_increment as postgresql do not handle it by itself

Comment: This isn't a table, its a model. I believe that sqlalchemy takes care of that. I am on sqllite for testing purposes. If I was writing raw query then maybe that would apply.

Comment: @amanraparia There is no need to explicitly set `autoincrement=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try without using `__init__`:

```py
something = Schedule()
something.start_time = request.form.get('start_time')
something.end_time = request.form.get('end_time')
something.duration =  request.form.get('duration')
something.action =  request.form.get('action')
something.location_name = request.form.get('location_name')
something.vehicle_name = request.form.get('vehicle_name')
something.post_time = request.form.get('post_time')
db.session.add(something)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and date objects as input. Assuming you're using [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) as your attribute input type, start by replacing the letter `T` with a whitespace, and then parse the whole string into Python datetime with `datetime.strptime`.

For instance:

> **2019-05-21T17:29**
> "**T**" appears literally in the string to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

```
from datetime import datetime

time = request.form.get('post_time')
time_old = time.replace('T', ' ')
time_new = datetime.strptime(time_old, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
post_time = time_new
```

More specifically:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Schedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = db.Column(db.String(20))
    end_time = db.Column(db.String(20))
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    action = db.Column(db.String(20))
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    vehicle_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    post_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)


@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method=='POST':
        time = request.form.get('post_time')
        time_old = time.replace('T', ' ')
        time_new = datetime.strptime(time_old, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        something = Schedule(
        start_time = request.form.get('start_time'),
        end_time = request.form.get('end_time'),
        duration =  request.form.get('duration'),
        action =  request.form.get('action'),
        location_name = request.form.get('location_name'),
        vehicle_name = request.form.get('vehicle_name'),
        post_time = time_new
        )
        db.session.add(something)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('input.html')
```